# Attach view to custom RelativeLayout in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-custom-view

I have a RelativeLayout with a match_parent main LinearLayout view and a secondary wrap_content LinearLayout which is initially not visible (gone).

The secondary one has to be shown at the top of the screen but declaring it at the beginning of the xml file, it is not shown even when set to visible because it's behind the main one.
That's why it's declared after the main LinearLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- FULL SCREEN CONTENT -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondary_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/f_white_transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would like to create a custom RelativeLayout to be used in all the xml files where I can obtain the same behavior and I can be able to put whatever content under the main layout.

Is there any way to do it still using xml?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `RelativeLayout` but do not use the benefits of it. You can declare the `wrap_content`-Layout in first place and add the parameter `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to it.

In your `match_parent`-LinearLayout you can add the parameter `android:layout_above="@+id/secondary_layout"` to make sure it will give space to the secondary Layout. This way `gone` will work, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the wrap_content -Layout to be really on top of the match_parent one.
That's why it's background is semi-transparent.

Comment: sorry, then I misunderstood your question. What is your question then? Do you want to define a custom class like `MyRelativeLayout` in XML? The same behaviour that you achieve there works with any other layout, so what do you want to get?

Comment: Yes I want a custom class MyRelativeLayout which includes automatically my wrap_content -Layout at the bottom without including manually it every time (I will use it as default in the whole app).
It's basically like including automatically a footer to a custom view.
Then I can use normally MyRelativeLayout attaching other layouts without adding manually each time the footer.

Comment: There you go with Fragments. RelativeLayout is a class and so would have to be defined as class in Java if you want it custom, but in your RelativeLayout you can very well define two frames which hold different fragments. Throughout your app you can fill them both or individually.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: Just exchange your `LinearLayout` with `FrameLayout` and use that to load the Fragments into it. To learn how to work with Fragments you should search for a tutorial, if you are not familiar with them. This is too complex to put in a few lines of code but sure the way to go for you.